# When using Node Reference module, how do I populate the user field as well?

Tags: drupal, drupal-nodes

I have a node type A (equipment) that references node type B (service ticket). When creating a new service ticket, I have a CCK field from which I choose a user (customer) to whom this service ticket belongs.

Then, I click the reverse link to create a new node A (equipment) which has CCK fields to record the equipment info I need for the service ticket (make, model, serial number, etc.).

What I'd like to do is add a CCK user reference field to the node type Equipment which is automatically populated by the user reference field in node type Service Ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with module [field reference](http://drupal.org/project/field_reference).